# Plotting the proportion of a categorial variable on the y-axis in R using ggplot with a numerical x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's some example data:

```
result  age
y   20
y   20
n   20
n   20
y   21
n   21
n   21
n   21
y   22
n   22
n   22
```

I would like to plot the proportion of "`y`" as a total of "`result`" on the y-axis against "`age`" on the x-axis, displayed as a line graph and preferably also with the dot representing the proportion / frequency of y (`geom_point`). I don't want to display "`n`". Preferably using `ggplot2` because I always use that.

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can summarize the data with dplyr and then plot the summarized data frame rather than the original data frame

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  group_by(age) %>% 
  summarise(p = mean(result == 'y')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = age, y = p)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: would you please know how we can add a regression line to this ggplot graph? Thanks