# Summarise() and group_by() in ggplot2 seem to be missing out rows of data in my data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

Recently I posted a question as to [how to plot a line and dot graph where the y-axis is the proportion of a categorical variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67448956/plotting-the-proportion-of-a-categorial-variable-on-the-y-axis-in-r-using-ggplot). I also posted some example data and I received a reply that worked for the dataset I posted, which was the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  group_by(age) %>% 
  summarise(p = mean(result == 'y')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = age, y = p)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line()
```

It works for the dataset I posted, and at first seems to produce a graph for the same type of data in a larger dataset (read as a .csv and assigned the name `'df'`), which is the following:

```
result  age
n   37
n   NA
n   40
n   NA
n   NA
n   30
p   23
n   40
n   34
n   28
c   40
n   24
n   NA
p   27
c   40
n   NA
n   28
n   40
n   NA
p   23
n   NA
n   28
p   28
n   NA
n   40
p   NA
n   28
n   NA
n   40
p   20
n   NA
n   NA
n   NA
n   30
n   24
n   NA
c   NA
n   30
n   NA
n   NA
NA  NA
n   NA
n   NA
NA  NA
n   NA
n   30
p   27
n   NA
n   31
n   28
n   NA
n   NA
n   NA
n   28
n   31
n   NA
n   24
c   18
p   30
n   NA
n   NA
n   31
n   30
n   NA
n   31
p   27
n   24
n   28
n   27
n   NA
p   26
n   31
n   24
NA  23
n   NA
n   NA
n   NA
n   NA
n   NA
n   NA
n   NA
n   NA
n   NA
n   NA
n   28
n   26
n   32
n   NA
c   NA
n   31
n   NA
p   32
n   NA
n   NA
p   26
n   NA
n   29
n   NA
n   31
n   29
n   NA
n   NA
n   NA
n   31
p   21
n   33
n   29
n   NA
p   NA
n   29
n   NA
n   NA
p   22
n   28
n   29
n   31
p   27
p   28
n   28
n   27
n   NA
```

When I run this code

```
df %>% 
    group_by(age) %>% 
    summarise(prop= mean(result == 'p')) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = age, y = prop)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 40, 1))
```

on a dataframe of this data, I get the following graph:

[image]
However, I can see in the graph than rows from my data are missing.
In the graph there is no data for age 23, yet in my data there is a 'p' at this age.
Furthermore, if I add new rows to the .csv that contain p entries in 'result' in the same rows as 23 entries for 'age', then update the dataframe in R and replot the graph, nothing happens.
Whereas if I do the exact same thing, entering 'p's for 18, the proportion of p at 18 in the graph does increase.

Can anyone work out what's going on? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Just like you have data for age 23, you also have data at age 23 with `NA`: see `filter(df, age==23)`. Change your `mean(.)` to `mean(., na.rm=TRUE)` and some of the missing ages will re-materialize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't handled `NA`s in your data. Consider this example -

```
mean(c(1, 3, 4))
#[1] 2.666667

mean(c(1, 3, 4, NA))
#[1] NA

mean(c(1, 3, 4, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 2.666667
```

Ignore the `NA` values with `na.rm = TRUE`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  group_by(age) %>% 
  summarise(p = mean(result == 'p', na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = age, y = p)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]